# get both slugs from same categories

Tags: mysql

With this query i get slug from category but i want to get second slug from child.

I want these slugs as result:  **category/sub-category/items**

```
SELECT i.*, c.slug as cat_slug FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN cats c ON c.id = i.cat_id ORDER BY i.id;
```

Categories table

```
+----------------------------------+
| id | parent_id |  name  |  slug  |
+----------------------------------+
| 1  |    0      |  Test  |  test  |
+----------------------------------+
| 2  |    1      |  Cool  |  cool  |
+----------------------------------+
| 3  |    0      |  Test5 | test5  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Items table

```
+---------------------------------+
| id | cat_id |  title  |  slug   |
+---------------------------------+
| 1  |   2    | Welcome | welcome |
+---------------------------------+
| 2  |   3    | Yeah    | yeah    |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you know that any parent can only have one generation of children?  In other words, are you guaranteeing that category 3 doesn't have parent 2?

Comment: yes but cannot be null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you make some assumptions about the structure of the data, specifically that there is only one layer, the following query is one way to make this work:

```
SELECT i.*, c.slug, subcat.slug as cat_slug,
  concat_ws('/', c.slug, subcat.slug, i.slug) as total_slug
FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN cats c ON c.id = i.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN cats subcat on c.parent_id = subcat.id
ORDER BY i.id;
```

[link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60e6fc/8)

This will not work with more than a two levels of categories.

Comment: Thank you, but litle bit strange in your sql fiddle why second query cat_slug is nulled ?